# Get Members from Delta Query on Groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

How do I return only Members from the delta API for group (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview?tabs=http)

Adding .Members & .Select() are not supported

[image]

```
await _graphServiceClient
                                    .Groups
                                    .Members
                                    .Delta()
                                    .Request()
                                    .Filter($"id  eq '{groupId}'")                                  
                                    .GetAsync();
```

On trying this:

```
        var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
        {
            new QueryOption("select", "members")
        };
       
            await _graphServiceClient
                                .Groups                                    
                                .Delta()
                                .Request(queryOptions)
                                .Filter($"id  eq '{groupId}'")
                                .GetAsync();
```

I see this error:

Message: Unrecognized query argument specified: 'select'. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select` method after `Request`.

```
var delta = await _graphServiceClient.Groups
    .Delta()
    .Request()
    .Select("members")
    .Filter($"id eq '{groupId}'")
    .GetAsync();
```

in your example with `QueryOption` you are missing `$` before `select`

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$select", "members")
};
   
await _graphServiceClient
                    .Groups                                    
                    .Delta()
                    .Request(queryOptions)
                    .Filter($"id eq '{groupId}'")
                    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: hey, are you familiar with delta query? I have a question -  I tried running delta query on a group containing 3 users using the above code and I see a total of 36 delta calls (36 pages using next link) to read the users from the group. On running the delta query on graph explorer, I see the data returned in 2 calls (2 pages). Why is that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code

var user = await graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"].Members
.Request( queryOptions )
.Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
.Select("displayname,id")
.GetAsync();

You can refer docs for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#example-4-use-search-and-odata-cast-to-get-user-membership-in-groups-with-display-names-that-contain-the-letters-pr-including-a-count-of-returned-objects

Hope this helps

Thanks